# Stripe::AuthenticationError No API key provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Working with a Rails 6.1.3 , Ruby 3.0 + Stripe, but I keep getting this error even if I think I got all the keys correctly included:

config > initializers > stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
:publishable_key => Rails.application.secrets.publishable_key,
:secret_key => Rails.application.secrets.secret_key
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

app > secrets.yml

```
development:
publishable_key: "pk_test_51ILY7..."
secret_key: "sk_test_51ILY7..."
```

In terminal once I call EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit, this is what I see:

```
stripe:
development:
publishable_key: 'pk_test_51ILY7...'
secret_key: 'sk_test_51ILY7...'
production:
publishable_key: 'pk_live_51ILY7...'
secret_key: 'sk_live_51ILY7...'
```

And the error I can see in my Rails terminal

```
Started POST "/checkout/create_order" for ::1 at 2021-02-22 18:25:10 +0100
Processing by CheckoutController#create_order as JS
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "id"=>"1"}
Order Load (0.9ms) SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/checkout_controller.rb:6:in `create_order'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 1751)

Stripe::AuthenticationError (No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.):
```

Any insights where is the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Is that exactly how the secrets file looks with the lack of indentation? If that's the case then it should be reading stripe as "". The other lines should be indented. Also, you'll need to call the production hash, too. `stripe[:production][:secret_key]`. Might be better to add these as env variables through dotenv and your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the environment variables are actually getting initialized. Is it possible the controller is running without the `stripe.rb` initialization?

You can print `p Stripe.api_key` as a diagnostic in the request handler to ensure it's been set up. Make sure it's not logging anywhere, though, and prefer to use a test key.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with your environment variables, try the following in your Stripe.rb file:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.after_initialize do
      # initialization code goes here
      Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:secret]
    end
  end
end
```

Also make sure to add your API keys in your credentials file by using the VIM editor. In your terminal, enter: *EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit* and then add your secret and public API keys:

[Credentials file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCEp2.png)

Hope it helps.